# Upgrading IOS on IPad 1

Tags: ipad

I updated candy crush saga as instructed by King on my IPad 1. Now it doesn't work at all and won't even allow me to reinstall after I deleted it. Is that because I'm still running IOS 5.1.1? Can I upgrade my operating system to IOS 7 or 8 on IPad 1?

Comment: You can downgrade to the last available version by downloading the app, and then hitting install.

Answer (score 2):

iOS 5.1.1 is the last version of iOS you can run on a first-generation iPad.